# Node-jose on android emulator cannot handle AzureAD JWT on react-native

Tags: android, react-native, azure-active-directory, node-jose

We have a React-native mobile app tha uses AzureAD for user management. Problem is that when logging in on android emulator in dev mode, for somereason Node-jose cannot verify Azure JWT against the key store. On manual inspection i can see that keystore contains required key and everything is fine. Even tested on Browser application wiht same keystore and JWT, and works fine there.

Also works fine on IOS, and i have heard from testers that prod build on android also works. But i need to get te Dev setup also working so icould continue development on it, but have been stuck on this Node-Jose issue.

With debbuggin all i have gotten is error "No Key Found", that comes within Node-Jose libary. What might be the issue? Right now im just thinking that it might be the Android emulators fault.

Comment: To better assist you, could you please provide more details about what you've already tried to solve the issue? Any code snippets, error messages, or specific steps you've taken so far would be helpful. This information will help the community better understand your problem and provide more accurate solutions.

Comment: @NaveenSharma i tried debugging to get more info but  to  no avail all my colleagues were also stumped. Still dont know what caused it.  eventually i downgraded the libary and it started working,